# How to up my bench?

Tags: bench-press

I bench 90kg for 10 reps after 3 months of training. I'm quite disappointed as my friend and I started at the same time and he's benching 110kg for 10 reps, although he weights 15 kgs heavier.  I weigh 75 kgs at 6"1.

I can do 15 reps of pullups in a set (full extension). I think i'm at 10 %bf (I can see my six pack nice and hard in good lighting). My curls aren't that great - just 35kgs for 10 reps (with good form), although to be fair I don't train my bi's a lot..

So yeah, how do I increase my bench?

Just to be clear, I don't squat or deadlift. As a straight man, I really really don't want to look like one of those guys with a big posterior. It's a disgusting look to me, but to each their own. I do have decent sized quads from leg extensions, which are more than good enough for aesthetics.

My program: 5 day split with bench every 3 days, lots of back work (T-bar rows + pullups) and lots of tricep work (pushdown machine + overhead extensions). Some quad extensions via machine.

EDIT: can't reply to the comment, so adding my response here

@David: No. I'm asking how to increase my bench. I provided a datapoint b/c I think my progress could've been better. Bodyweight might be factor, but it isn't everything.

@Thomas Not really. I know several guys who are 100kg+ reps in like 4-5 months of training.

@C.Lange Of course I meant full reps, to lockout. I don't know what program you follow, but browsing through this site it seems like everyone wants to squat/deadlift for "anabolic hormones." That's some crazy BS lol. If you want a stronger bench and strong arms, you have to bench. If you want big glutes, go squat. Talk to any big guy (non-powerlifter) at a gym with BIG arms and you'll rarely see them deadlifting/squatting. If you're training for aesthetics you need to work our back/triceps/chest. My friend and I squatted just a couple times for fun in the last 3 months - there's literally no benefit to it other than increasing glute size (which is not what a straight man should go for, but to each their own)

@Eric how long do newbie gains last?

Also, I just a new PR today: 95KGs for 8 reps :D

LMAO what's with all the downvotes?

LMAOOO continue deleting my edits, mods. This place is an elitist, jerkfest full of newbie gym scientists pretending to know more about strength than actually having the strength to bench a decent weight. Have fun downvoting, editing out my posts, and pretending to be smart, MR DEE.

Comment: So you're asking why your friend, who is 20% heavier than you, can lift 12% more weight than you in the bench press?

Comment: 90 kg for 10 after three months of training is ridiculously good progress.

Comment: I agree with Thomas. I can't do 100 kg for 10 reps... and it's been years. Unless you're doing some sort of 1/4 reps, I think you'd be the one giving advice. Just keep lifting, eating, resting and repeating.

Comment: I agree, that progress is really good! I've been lifting for ~8 years and can do 11 reps of 102kg at 73kg. At 3 months I wasn't even close to what you are doing, largely due to my starting weight being 54kg. Regardless, C. Lange's answer is spot on here. Your friend is lifting more than you because he weighs more. Eat more, train hard, don't worry so much about abs and your lifts will go up quickly. Just be aware that your newbie gains won't last forever and your progress will slow down drastically as you get more experienced.

Comment: @Mike, I rejected the edit because you're editing/commenting from the wrong account. You can always comment on your own post. In this case, add comments from "Mike" instead of editing in comments from "pfft". Otherwise, someone needs to approve the question edit and details are lost or delayed.

Comment: Newbie gains are just the phenomenon of gaining muscle/strength quickly. It doesn't really have a set amount of time that they last. The closer you get to your natural limit, the slower your gains will be. Early progress is dictated by neurological adaptations, muscular adaptations, and improvements to form. Perfecting form is fast, so are neurological adaptations. Muscular adaptations are slow and slow down even more as you reach your natural limits.

Answer (score 5):

You've got two pathways to increase your bench press: more muscle and better technique. Both have quite a few answers on the site so you can browse around but the summary of each is this:

- More muscle will drive more weight. This is obvious. You eat big, train hard, and rest adequately. Increasing your bench press frequency can help speed up progress so long as you're recovering enough. Bench press accessories are very useful (e.g. dumbbell, paused barbell, 3-2-0 tempo). Make sure you're consuming enough protein, and if your %bf is a concern, watch the calorie+fat content.
- Better technique will drive more weight. This will really be dependent on how you lift and what your lift looks like. Powerlifting methods look at decreasing ROM for efficiency (back arch, wider grip, lower touch point). Bodybuilding methods usually try to make the lift more difficult, in which case, see point #1.